# Replace string with another string with regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace, pattern-matching

When i get a string such as `<iframe width="500"/>`.

I am trying to change `width="500"` to `width="100%"` within that string variable.

I have:

```
if(variableName.contains("width="*"") { variableName = variableName.Replace("width="*"", "100%"); }
```

That isn't doing what I'm hoping to do as explained above. Another note is that the width of `500` may be another random number such as `650` or even be `500px`.

Any ideas of how I should go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: The first thing I noticed in your code is that you use quotes inside your string without escaping it, so `"width="*""` will actually try to multiply the string `"width="` with the string `""`, which is wrong. You escape a special char within a string with \ (e.g. `\"`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
string g = "<iframe width=\"500\"/>";

string pattern = "width=\"\\d+\"";
if (Regex.IsMatch(g, pattern))
{
    string replaced = Regex.Replace(g, pattern, "width=\"100%\"");

}
```

explanation:

[Regex.IsMatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch(v=vs.110).aspx) will tell you if a the string contains your pattern.

[Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) will replace the pattern to a desired string

`\d+` : looks for one or more occurences of a digit

EDIT:

> may be another random number such as 650 or even be 500px.

you can use this patter:

```
string pattern = "width=\"\\d+(px)?\"";
```

`(pc)?`: means an optional `px` element after the number which can occur 0 or 1 times

Comment: Maybe add `(px)?` or something alike in your regex so 500px would be changed too.

Comment: @Rafalon thank you, I missed that end part when reading the question :)

Comment: You're welcome. Note that `?` would be more accurate than `*` as it is unlikely to find strings like `width="500pxpxpxpx"`. (`?` means 0 or 1 occurence).

Comment: @Rafalon you are right! thanx did not think of the repetition of pxpxpxp